# Unable to create a maven project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache, maven, maven-resources-plugin

I am trying to create a maven project and its showing the below error

> Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
> Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5

I have m2e plugin installed in my eclipse and the system variable is also set.

> C:\Users\852346>mvn -v
>
> Apache Maven 3.3.1 (cab6659f9874fa96462afef40fcf6bc033d58c1c; 2015-03-14T01:40:2
> 7+05:30)
> Maven home: D:\apache-maven-3.3.1
> Java version: 1.7.0_25, vendor: Oracle Corporation
> Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
> Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
> OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"**

But I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I forgot to add the proxy server I was using in settings.xml file in .m2/ directory.